# Microsoft Word and Outlook with Black Theme like Visual Studio?

Tags: microsoft-word, themes

Is there a way to change Microsoft Windows theme and all their application such as Microsoft Word, Excel, Outlook and others completely with black theme, black background, and easy for eyes .... just like Visual Studio.

Looking at white background on a long time make my eyes hurts.

Microsoft Windows has "High Contrast" setting. However, the color is not easy for eyes. I'm looking something like Visual Studio color, or sublime color.

Microsoft outlook has [Dark Theme](https://www.codetwo.com/blog/changing-background-colors-in-outlook-2007-2010-and-2013/) ... but I wish the background can be changed to completely black just like the screenshot below.  However, this is not Microsoft Outlook.

[image]

Comment: There is a black theme (mostly) in Outlook 2013 and 2016 too. Its in Start->Account if my memory serves me correctly. At least, the place where you can set a theme, there is a black theme nowadays too.

Answer (score 0):

On either Word or Outlook, go to File -> Options -> General -> Personalize your version of Microsoft Office. Set Office Theme to Black.

**Word**
[image: Word option]

**Outlook**
[image: Outlook option]